# How do I set a fixed size of a background image?

Tags: html, css

How do I set a  fixed size of a background image?

I set the width and height right now but when I increase or decrease my browser window image gets blocked. How can Ifix that?
[image]

Image will be blocked slowly when I decreased window size:
[image]

Here is my code :-

```
.bg{
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80%;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/interview.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of new lines. Added comments on them.

```css
.bg{
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 80%; /*I'd remove this and edit the original photo*/
  border-bottom-right-radius: 80%; /*I'd remove this and edit the original photo*/
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3b/8a/d2/3b8ad2c7b1be2caf24321c852103598a.jpg");
  background-size: contain; /*From cover to contain*/
  background-position: top !important; /*New - Can change to center*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important; /*New*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position of you `bg` component to `fixed`

You new CSS class will look like this:

```
.bg{
   height: 600px;
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 80%;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 80%;
   background-image: url("/assets/images/interview.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   //modifications
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position:'fixed';
   top:0;
   left:0;
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code but image will be fixed for whole page

Comment: Then i think you also need to set width to a value.